# Updating value of textbox getting value from first text box only

Tags: javascript, jquery, textbox

I have cart page in which text box is present for updating quantity, I'm using jquery to listen to the click event & get the values of productid & the textbox. Productid I'm getting fine but value of textbox always is the value in first textbox.

Here is the code of cart file

```
echo "<tr>";
            echo "<th><img src=".$row["image_location"]."></th>";
            echo "<th>".$row["product_name"]."</th>";
            echo "<th><input type='text' id='quantity' name='quantity' required='required' autocomplete='off' value=".$row["quantity"].">";
            echo "&nbsp";
            echo $row["type"]."</th>";
            echo "<th>".$row["price"]."</th>";
            echo "<th>"."&#8377;&nbsp;".$subtotal."</th>";
            echo "<th><div class='buttoncircle' id='".$row["productid"]."'>Update</div></th>";
            echo "<th><a href='removefromcart.php?productid={$row["productid"]}' class='buttoncircle' style='margin-left:-65px'>Remove</a></th>";
        echo "</tr>";
```

Here is the code for javascript.

```
<script>
$('.buttoncircle').live('click',function() {
    var productid = $(this).attr('id');
    var quantity = $('#quantity').val();
    window.open('db_changequantity.php?quantity='+quantity+'&productid='+productid,'_self');
});
```

Can anyone help calling the value of particular textbox & not from the first one only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added dynamic id for the quantity filed - `id='quantity_".$row["productid"]."'` and mapped the same in javascript `var quantity = $('#quantity_'+productid).val();`.

In PHP

```
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th><img src=".$row["image_location"]."></th>";
    echo "<th>".$row["product_name"]."</th>";
    echo "<th><input type='text' id='quantity_".$row["productid"]."' name='quantity' required='required' autocomplete='off' value=".$row["quantity"].">";
    echo "&nbsp";
    echo $row["type"]."</th>";
    echo "<th>".$row["price"]."</th>";
    echo "<th>"."&#8377;&nbsp;".$subtotal."</th>";
    echo "<th><div class='buttoncircle' id='".$row["productid"]."'>Update</div></th>";
    echo "<th><a href='removefromcart.php?productid={$row["productid"]}' class='buttoncircle' style='margin-left:-65px'>Remove</a></th>";
    echo "</tr>";
```

Javascript:

```
    $('.buttoncircle').live('click',function() {
    var productid = $(this).attr('id');
    var quantity = $('#quantity_'+productid).val();
    window.open('db_changequantity.php?quantity='+quantity+'&productid='+productid,'_self');
});
```

Comment: This is the URL: db_changequantity.php?quantity=undefined&productid=32.
See undefined quantity??

Comment: Do you have firebig in your mozila browser? Check `id='quantity_".$row["productid"]."'` it properly redned in source

Comment: `id=quantity_".$row["productid"]` can you replace this in qty field column?

Comment: Sorry buddy, my mistake, forgot to add something, your answer is perfect. Thanks a ton:)

Comment: One question though, my css elements are lost for quantity field, can I apply the same elements to dynamic ids?? Or should I make another class itself??

Comment: you can use class instead of `id`